# Only allow users from specific referrer (redirect the rest) - HTACCESS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, referrer, http-referer

I've been trying to block access from everyone that is trying to see a .php page without coming from my specific tracking link.

I want that if they're not coming from my link, they be redirected to another website.
I tried using .htaccess method as following:

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# allow these referers to passthrough
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# redirect everything else
RewriteRule ^ http://anotherDomain.com/ [R,L]
```

this is because http://subdomain.domain.com is a tracking url that redirects to website.php  but it seems that is not working, and despite any referrer, or even typing the url for website.php directly in toolbar is taking the user to website.php.

what I want to achieve is that only from subdomain.domain.com users can see website.php

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that using `order deny,allow`, put this into your .htaccess:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from subdomain.domain.com
```

This will deny everyone access unless they visit via `subdomain.domain.com`

Then to redirect the users who're not coming from `subdomain.domain.com` you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.subdomain.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

For Apache 2.4:

You can use an IF directive since you're using 2.4:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.subdomain.domain.com'">
Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</If>
```

and for the `order deny,allow` add the following around it:

```
<Limit GET>
</Limit>
```

Comment: uhm.. is not working, I'm getting 403 for every request, even if coming from subdomain.domain.com

Comment: What version of Apache are you running?

Comment: httpd 2.4.18 (Unix)

Comment: Since you're using 2.4, I've added an edit of an alternative method for you to try. Hope that helps.

Comment: ok, now is working, but I just found that my tracking service is doing a DMR (double meta refresh) so the referer was getting as blank (I don't know why in the developer console I can see the referer but when linking to "what's my refer" website I see that the referer is blank... It would be great if there was a way to join both worlds, to have DMR and to block people that comes from other domain...

Comment: Can we make this `allow from subdomain.domain.com` a particular URL instead rather than a domain? Or more than one URL or we can write multiple rules for it?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!your-valid-referer.example.com"
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
```

#### Details

- `RewriteCond` - do a comparison of:
- `"%{HTTP_REFERER}"` - the current [referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) at the time of the request; against:
- `"!your-valid-referer.example.com"` - the valid referer; and if it isn't:
- `RewriteRule ^.*$` - no matter what it is;
- `[F]` - don't give access to it. Assign an HTTP status code of `403` aka `Forbidden`.

### OP's case

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!subdomain.domain.com"
RewriteRule ^ http://anotherDomain.com/ [R,L]
```