# How to control over outgoing static content

Tags: php, security, cross-domain, centos7, cdn

I want to control outgoing static content for my domain. I have created a domain something like CDN to deliver static content for my client's websites. Now I want to control this -

For example, if my CDN domain is " cdn.com " and my client's website is " client-1.com " then how can I allow this " client-1.com " to use static content for example " http://cdn.com/style.css" from my site but no other website can use untile I allow it from my end.

Is there any script, cms, or any system?

Thanks

Comment: Check the referer header at the CDN. It is spoofable but unless you have assets that require security it should be good enough.

Comment: If you have a solution share it.

Comment: Although you could do this in [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14854338/231316), I would recommend moving this to the server-level for performance. Here's an [Nginx version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917016/231316) and an [Apache one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38130375/231316).

Comment: Thank you so much :)