# How do I limit access to a page only through redirect from another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have two web pages, `index.html` and `home.html`. I'm trying to make `home.html` can only be accessed from `index.html` so that if a user inputs `www.mywbpage.home.html`, they'll be redirected to an error page or to `index.html`..

I linked `index.html` to home.html with a JS button.

Tried searching all over but the PHP, JS and .htaccess codes I got didn't work...

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130081/only-allow-users-from-specific-referrer-redirect-the-rest-htaccess. Basically you need to check referer in your web server.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean for individual local files not subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without server side, but you know this is a bit sketchy.

**index.html**

```
var value = "visited";    // or the date of visit!
localStorage.setItem('my_flag', "visited");
```

**home.html**

```
var value = localStorage.getItem('my_flag');
if (value != "visited") {
    window.location = "index.html";
}
localStorage.removeItem("my_flag");
```

Comment: Can you tell me the pros and cons of using this?

Comment: It's ok I guess, just not perfectly secure because this all happens on client side. Also, he can visit index.html then another page then home.html and it will work - if that's a problem. Also, `sessionStorage` is also acceptable.

Comment: This serves the purpose, And it redirects back to the index file if it didn't come from there at first..  thank you...

Answer (score 1):

you can use sessionStorage to do that
first on the load index page put

```
sessionStorage.setItem('home', 'true');
```

second, if you are on the home page check if

```
sessionStorage.getItem('home')=="true"
```

if it is true let him there else redirect

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this helps, but a simple approach would be:

1. Convert index.html and home.html to index.php and home.php, in its simple form just renaming the file should be enough.
2. In home.php, add the check for HTTP_REFERER header like below:

```
<?php
$prev_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if($prev_url != "/") {  /* or use fully qualified url for index */
    header("Location: /");
    exit;
}
?>
<!-- here on put the home.html content -->
```

*Note This is highly insecure and not recommended as `HTTP_REFERER` can easily be spoofed